# GCC 4.9 gives error when checking inline function's pointer (with static_assert)

Tags: c++, function, templates, inline, static-assert

Consider the following case

```
typedef void (*foo)();
template<foo f>
struct bar {
     static_assert(f!=nullptr,"f == null!");
};

void baz() {}
inline void bax() {  }

bar<baz> ok;
bar<bax> bad; // error: non-constant condition for static assertion
```

Both `baz` and `bax` are accepted as template arguments. 
It indicates that both are accepted as constants. 
However, at `static_assert` they appears to be different (at least in gcc 4.9) - `bax` is not a constant anymore.

My assumption was that `static_assert` and template evaluate constantness identically. 
E.g. either error should be

- 'bax is not a valid template argument' or
- `static_assert` should not raise non-constant condition error.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Unless `foo` is declared somewhere, I expect this won't compile at all...

Comment: fixed, lost typedef void (*foo)(); added

Comment: VC++ 14.0 accepts both.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4542a0bf5217a42).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  - in other instantiation of bar in could:  bar<nullptr> nill;

Comment: @Quentin: not with gcc... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72fd4b666aa73737

Comment: Works in clang++ 3.7 [about a week or two prior to 3.7-RC1], not in gcc 4.9.2. Suspect that it's a gcc bug.

Comment: The only difference I see in the standard is that a template argument accepts _converted constant expression_.  
(5.20.4.: "A _converted constant expression_ of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only (...) such expressions may be used in `new` expressions, as case expressions, as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed, as array bounds, and as non-type template arguments.")

Comment: There is no way that a template value parameter is not a compile time constant, and comparing such a pointer to `nullptr` should be a constant expression.  If the standard actually agrees with gcc, this is just a sign there is a defect in the standard that gcc should be ignoring anyhow.

Comment: Is this [GCC bugzilla thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52036) related to this problem? Clang3.6 can compile the code in the bugzilla, but gcc5+ and gcc6HEAD can't do.

Comment: g++ 4.7.2.5 return an error. `non-constant condition for static assertion` which I believe is the correct behavior

Answer (score 1):

Just yet another `GCC` bug, update to newer version, or migrate to `LLVM` (`clang`).

> See issue ticket for details:
> https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52036

Answer (score -1):

When a function is inlined, the pointer to the function does not exist. So we can not compare it with nullptr.

Whether a function is eventually inlined or not, depends on the compiler. `inline` keyword does not guarantee that.

Comment: Wrong: if you take the address of a function (even an `inline`d one) the compiler should give it (and not always inline that function)